# Why does the Object class have Thread methods?

Tags: java, api-design

Why does the `Object` class have thread-related methods, like `wait()`, `notify()`, `notifyAll()`?

We need to extend `Thread` or implement `Runnable` to give Thread-like behavior to a class. So why weren't they made part of any `Thread` or `Runnable` object?

Comment: This question isn't really conclusively answerable by more than a very small group of people. The reason is that someone somewhere at some point for some reason decided to make  every object a condition variable.

Answer (score 5):

Java concurrency model uses locks to implement mutually exclusive access to objects in a multi-threaded environment and locks are associated with every object in Java (of type 'Object'), not only with Threads.

1) Wait and notify are communication mechanism between two threads in Java. And `Object` class is correct place to make them available for every object as it is the superclass of all Objects.

2) Locks are made available on per Object basis, which is another reason wait and notify is declared in Object class rather then Thread class.

Comment: why dint java provide an interface for this functionality? Why did it have to be Object class and force this functionality on all objects when there might be cases where all execution is done in a single thread

Answer (score 0):

If a thread has locked on an object instance, calling notify on that object instance will wake up those threads. So, since a lock is an object instance, operations related to that lock belong to the object instance.